# issue with vs2010 C# windows voice recognition

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, voice-recognition

I have ran into an interesting issue with my voice recognition code for C#. I have had this code work before, but I migrated it to another project and it just wont work. I must be missing something, because there are no errors or warnings about the speech recognition and I do have the reference for speech. Here is the main function:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prgm = new Program();
        string[] argument = prgm.readConfigFile();
        if(argument[2].ToLower().Contains("true"))
        {
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
            recognizer.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
            recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
            recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        }
        prgm._con.updateConsole(argument, prgm._list);
    }

    static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
    }
```

along with the recognizer:

```
    recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

I did add the using System.Speech at the top of my code. When ever I start talking the event handler should start, but it never gets hit (checked with breakpoint). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check to make sure the Microphone isn't muted?

Comment: Code looks fine and works.  Very unclear how you stop the main thread from exiting.  Replace updateConsole() with Console.ReadLine() and try again.

Comment: sorry for late response, but the microphone was not muted and I will try your suggestion Hans Passant.

Comment: well I put the code in a fresh project and worked just fine. so I will check the other parts of the code and see why it is not working.